# OpenSearch Dashboards health status red, everything else green

Tags: amazon-web-services, elasticsearch, kibana, opensearch

We have an OpenSearch domain on AWS.

Sometimes **Cluster status** and **OpenSearch Dashboards health status** goes into yellow for a few minutes which is fine I guess.

But today **OpenSearch Dashboards health status** went into red and is there for a few hours now. Everything else works except the dashboards, which gives error 503: `{"Message":"Http request timed out connecting"}`

[image: aws console graphs]

```json
{
  "cluster_name" : "779754160511:telemetry",
  "status" : "green",
  "timed_out" : false,
  "number_of_nodes" : 2,
  "number_of_data_nodes" : 2,
  "discovered_master" : true,
  "discovered_cluster_manager" : true,
  "active_primary_shards" : 166,
  "active_shards" : 332,
  "relocating_shards" : 0,
  "initializing_shards" : 0,
  "unassigned_shards" : 0,
  "delayed_unassigned_shards" : 0,
  "number_of_pending_tasks" : 0,
  "number_of_in_flight_fetch" : 0,
  "task_max_waiting_in_queue_millis" : 0,
  "active_shards_percent_as_number" : 100.0
}
```

I finally tried updating to an instance with more RAM, but the status is still red.

How could I solve this? Is there a way to restart the domain or debug in someway?

Comment: How many total shards do you have? 332? If the cluster for some reason(RAM, CPU etc) went red and got stabalized but the dashboard status has remained red, it means the dashboard node was not able to recover successfuly. You need to open a ticket and ask support to intervene. It won't do anything by itself. From what I have understood, there is just one dashbaord node even if your domain is in multiaz.

Comment: you could theoretically, make some change which triggers a blue green deployment and maybe change the dashboard node but it's a bad practice and aws doesn't suggest to make any changes when there is an issue.

Comment: @Riz I See. How do I do that? I tried [here](https://support.console.aws.amazon.com/support/home?region=eu-central-1#/case/create) but it says "Technical support is unavailable under the Basic Support plan".

Comment: @Riz I have tried triggering blue green deployment. Didn't help unfortunately...

Comment: I would create a backup and restore it to a new domain. I am afraid nothing else can be done from your side. this is what support had said to me when i had a similar issue. They had intervened in my case.